# g++ won't play nice with wx-config

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets

I'm on windows using mingw and when i use the following to try and compile my wxWidgets code

```
g++ main.cpp `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags`
```

I get the following error

```
g++: `wx-config: No such file or directory
g++: `wx-config: No such file or directory
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-flibs`"
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fcxxflags`"
```

And I cannot figure out what to do to make g++ play nice with wx-config

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you just type `wx-config` on the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What shell are you using? Back quotes don't work on the Windows command prompt. You may need to use msys and bash.

Comment: Aha I was assuming they did work in command prompt, thanks for the clarification