# Why won't g++ compile a simple GTK program?

Tags: c++, c, g++, wxwidgets, gtk3

I'm beginning to teach myself a bit of C++ these days off, and I decided to learn some GUI programming in the meantime. Thing is, it just won't compile, either using GTK (Windows bundle 3.6.4) or wxWidgets (3.0.0). The error I get is similar for both, so I'm sticking with GTK+ for this question.

After 5 days (7 recompiles of wx, many tutorials, SO questions and google), this is how I'm trying to compile the [code](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html) (I'm under Windows 7, 64 bits, and it's not an option to switch to Linux right now):

```
@echo off

set cygpath=C:\Cygwin\bin
set filename=simple

%cygpath%\bash.exe -c "gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o %filename% %filename%.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)"

echo.
pause
```

But the only output I get is this (backtilts instead of `$()` returns the same thing):

```
: Invalid argument
: Invalid argument
```

I tried the same without Cygwin at first, but the results were:

```
gcc: error: $(pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0): No such file or directory
gcc: error: $(pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0): No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
```

Using quotes or double quotes didn't help at all. I tried all these in both cygwin-bash or Windwos prompt

I'm totally new to C++, wxWidgets and GTK+ and I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432004/g-wont-play-nice-with-wx-config), but since it didn't solve my problem and I can't comment because of reputation, I thought I had to open a new question.

Also, I changed the compiler to [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) because I couldn't compile wx with MinGW. Is this somewhat related? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**: Sorry, just realized that the sample was written in C, not C++. I'm adding the tag now. (However, the error is the same with the C++ code I'm using for wx, so I'm keeping the C++ tag.)

Comment: It seems that `cmd.exe` doesn't do inline variable substitution in strings. (Windows gurus please confirm or refute that.)

Comment: @H2CO2: Yes, it does replace variables in strings. Except in `cmd` variables are spelled `%LIKE_THIS%` not `$(LIKE_THIS)`.

Comment: @BillyONeal 3, not 2 (I would miss my double negative charge). And that seems pretty logical, but does `%it --work with /commands/too%`?

Comment: @H2CO3: No, there is no command support that way.

Comment: @H2CO3: And the Windows org is aggressively pushing people to use PowerShell instead of changing `cmd` due to the massive backcompat headache that would cause.

Comment: @BillyONeal Ugh... why can't everyone just use Bash...!? (rhetorical)

Comment: Just write a bash script and then have your .bat file call bash.exe with the bash script

Comment: What gets output if you run the command: `%cygpath%\bash.exe -c "echo gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o %filename% %filename%.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)"`

Comment: @Brandin thats exactly what I'm doing. `%cygpath%\bash.exe` is tha call for it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `gcc -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/incl
ude/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/p
ixman-1 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/in
clude/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gt
 -o simple simple.c -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole
32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin` (cutting it a bit because of SO)

Comment: @Ryu No I mean rather than stuffing all the commands into the -c parameter, you would have an easier time if you write the commands into a dedicated "myscript.sh" file and then do `%cygpath%\bash.exe myscript.sh`

Comment: @Brandin oh, this. Because that was the way I got to work, no deep meaning. Besides, in the answer bellow, this was suggested too, and didn't work either.

Comment: @Ryu: it looks like the compiler maybe doesn't like the Windows-style paths with drive letters. You may need to somehow convince `pkg-config` to spit out paths using a Cygwin mount point, such as `/c/gtk/include/cairo` or `/cygdrive/c/gtk/include/cairo` instead of `C:/gtk/include/cairo`. If you can't do that, perhaps a simple filter script can do that for you.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I see... Actually, I found that, setting variable with the results for `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`, it seams to stop complaining. So, I'm sticking with this for now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT a gcc issue. This is a scripting/shell/bash/environment issue.

```
gcc: error: $(pkg-config: No such file or directory
```

This line denotes that 'gcc' saw `$(pkg-config` where it was expecting a file name; Linux apps expect command-line substitution to have been done for them by the shell invoking them.

That means that the shell did not consume `$(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)` and perform substitution on it.

You might want to try making a bash script, gtkcc.sh, which does this for you and inserts the relevant parameters in the appropriate places.

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: gtkcc.sh <filename>
filename="$1"; shift
if [ -z "${filename}" ]; then echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"; exit 255; fi
if [ ! -f "${filename}.c" ]; then echo "Cannot find ${filename}.c"; exit 255; fi

gtkCFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)"
gtkLDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)"

cmd="gcc ${gtkCFLAGS} -o \"${filename}\" \"${filename}.c\" ${gtkLDFLAGS}"
echo $cmd >${TMP}/gtkcc.log
eval $cmd
```

Save as gtkcc.sh or gtkcc, `chmod a+rx gtkcc.sh`

Change your bat file to invoke:

```
%cygpath%\bash.exe gtkcc.sh %filename%
```

If it doesn't work, start a bash and consult ${TMP}/gtkcc.log, otherwise you can comment out the echo line.

Comment: The error you're referring only shows when I call gcc from the windows terminal. Using Cygwin's bash, the error is `: Invalid argument`. I also tried your suggestion and it didn't work, giving now this: `: No such file or directoryash
gtkcc.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
gtkcc.sh: line 4: $'shift\r': command not found
gtkcc.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: That means you have Windows line endings in the .sh file and bash is barfing on the character. You need to convert to Unix file endings with `dos2unix gtkcc.sh`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/cygwin-r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile

Another option would be to get into the habit of using something like Notepad++ (which will let you specify line ending mode) rather than notepad.

Comment: I actually code with Emacs or Notepad++ (though I only use NP++ for quick edits), but anyway... I changed the EOL to Unix, and now it stoped the long error. The other one is still there, though. The `: Invalid Argument`, I mean.

Comment: What - if anything - is it writing to /tmp/gtkcc.log?

Comment: Only `: Invalid Argument`. But it seams that, if I set a variabla with the contents of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`, Windows stops complaining and start to work. So I'm sticking with this for now. Thanks for your time and sorry for anything.